# Is there a way to use the chrome devTools API to get the informations in the devTools about the selected element?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

i couldn't find a way to do that,only get the selected html node, i'm more interested in the style information that the devTools provide.

Comment: [No such API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities) exposed in devtools UI, but if you use an external tool like Puppeteer there are various [CSS get commands](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/CSS) in the devtools protocol.

Comment: interestring, i have to check them out thanks